# What are "Inception" and "AverageSoFar" parameters in the FinancialDerivative[{"AsianGeometric" ... function?

Tags: finance

I cannot find parameterisation manual anywhere for the `FinancialDerivative` function. Kind thanks!

---

By experimentation, my guess is that `"Inception"` designates time when the averaging starts (since it seems to have to be less than `"Expiration"`)!?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation >> FinancialDerivative >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialDerivative.html):

[image]